# How to run a program installed through terminal

Tags: paths, installed-programs

I followed [these simple directions](https://github.com/platformsh/platformsh-cli) to download and install platform.sh onto my machine. Basically I just ran `curl -sS https://platform.sh/cli/installer | php` from my default directory (the directory you go to when you type `cd` in terminal) using the terminal. Looks like everything installed OK.

The directions say to then just run `platform` from the terminal to start using it. But when I run `platform` from the same directory the terminal just tells me 'platform: command not found'.

I think maybe there is some sort of path issue or something. I'm not very good with Linux so probably I just don't understand what's going on. I think maybe i have to reference the program through some sort of path, but I don't know what the path to the program would be. Also, I would like to make it easier on myself so I could just run the program by typing `platform` instead of having to type out the whole path everytime.

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The installer added the following snippet to `~/.bashrc` on my system:

```
# Automatically added by Platform.sh CLI installer
export PATH="/home/andrew/.platformsh/bin:$PATH"
. '/home/andrew/.platformsh/shell-config.rc' 2>/dev/null
```

Thus extending your `$PATH`, this means that for the first run you must use *two commands*:

```
source ~/.bashrc
platform
```

Otherwise your system will not look in the *very* non-standard location: `$HOME/.platformsh/bin`. When you have logged out and logged back in you will not need the `source ~/.bashrc` line again...